# What are the Kotlin class initialisation semantics?

Tags: class, constructor, initialization, kotlin

I haven't been able to find anything in the language definition that explains the initialisation of a class in Kotlin.

```
import java.util.Properties

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val out = MyClass()
    out.fn()
}

class MyClass {
    private val a = Properties() // 1

    init {
        fn()
    }

    public fun fn() {
        println("Fn called.  a = $a")
    }

    //  private val a = Properties() // 2
}
```

The results of running this program change depending whether the property is initialised at (1) or at (2).

I'm surprised that the declaration order is relevant in the language and would like to understand the decisions behind this.  My expectation would be that properties are initialised before the constructor body is invoked.

Answer (score 16):

> My expectation would be that properties are initialised before the constructor body is invoked.

Well, `init` block is not a [constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html). It is a different construct which allows you to perform the initialization of the object and they [init blocks] are performed in the declaration order with the property initializers.

Constructors are a different beast ant they are performed after all the properties were initialized and all init blocks were performed. Look at the following example:

```
class A(val value: Int) {
    constructor(): this(0) {        
        println("Constructor")
    }    

    init {
        println("Init block")
    }
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val a = A()
}
```

Output is:

```
Init block  
Constructor
```

You can place the `init` block wherever you want: before the `constructor` or after it; it will always be performed *before* the `A`'s constructor (secondary constructor, in this example).

Comment: This is not entirely correct. `init` blocks contain code which is included in the primary constructor. In your example, they are executed because the secondary constructor delegates to the primary constructor using the `: this(0)` syntax. If a secondary constructor does not delegate to the primary constructor, `init` blocks will not be executed when the class is initialized using that constructor.

Comment: Hi Aga / Yole - thanks for your answers.  I probably should have stated I'm a Kotlin n00b, but that's probably clear from my question.

I think both your responses come from familiarity with the language.  When I read this definition of Kotlin https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-docs.pdf the only reference I find to init is:

"The primary constructor cannot contain any code. Initialization code can be placed in initializer blocks, which are prefixed with the init keyword"

Nothing is stated about the order of initialisation however. (That I can see)

Comment: @aga you can edit your answer based on the feedback so it is clear to new people reading this without having to scan the comments as well.  Editing is here in SO just for that reason, to always create clear answers based on ongoing feedback.  I'll upvote your answer when it is clearer.  You may want to exclude the secondary constructor from the example, then add an additional note about it.  They aren't overly common and it confuses the main point of your answer.

Comment: @yole I realize your answer is a bit old, but I'm hoping you can clarify something for me. You mention "If a secondary constructor does not delegate to the primary constructor..." - in what case can this happen? From the Kotlin docs: "If the class has a primary constructor, each secondary constructor needs to delegate to the primary constructor, either directly or indirectly through another secondary constructor(s)." Has this not always been the case?

Comment: The docs are correct. If a class does _not_ have a primary constructor, it can have multiple secondary constructors, each of which can delegate to a different superclass constructor.

Comment: @yole Your comment is confusing me. What is not entirely correct? You mean init block not execute before constructor all the time?

Comment: I am not defining any primary constructor but still `init blocks` are being called.

    `fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        val event = Event()
    }

class Event {
    val name: String
    constructor(name: String = "undefined"){
        this.name = name
        println("constructor called")
    }
    init {
        println("block 1")
    }

    init {
        println("block 2")
    }
}`

Output:

`block 1
block 2
constructor called`

Answer (score 6):

Simply put: when an instance of a class is created, (almost) firstly runs the constructor of the parent class (if present), then the primary constructor.

The primary constructor executes code declared in the class body from the top to the bottom. Also the names became available by the same rule:

```
class Foo(a: String = "might be first"
          val b: String = "second" + a) : Boo(a + b + "third"){
    var c = a + "fourth" + b

    init {print("fifth: $c")}

    val d = "sixth"
    init {print("seventh: the end of the primary constructor"}
}
```

If you invoke a secondary constructor, then it works after the primary one as it is composed in the chain (similar to invoking the parent constructors).

Comment: Can you reword when sure about the ordering and can remove "almost" and "might be" so that it is a decisive answer.  Or defer to the answer from @aga