# Object constructor and Delegates.notNull

Tags: kotlin

```
object WalletConfig {

    init {
        fill(HashMap<String, String>())
    }

    var clientUrl: String by Delegates.notNull()
        private set

    fun fill(settingMap: Map<String, String>) {
        try {
            clientUrl = settingMap["URL_CLIENT"] ?: ""
        } catch(ex:Exception) { }
    }
}
```

throw ex: fill: Load 'wallet.config' config file: java.lang.NullPointerException at ru.WalletConfig.setClientUrl(WalletConfig.kt)

Comment: Are you sure the code you pasted is the one that is failing with NPE? It doesn't compile even.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is caused by the miss ordered `init` block and property initializer. As stated in the [answer about class initialization semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688821/what-are-the-kotlin-class-initialisation-semantics). The **`init`** block is not the constructor - its code is included in the primary constructor.

The following example:

```
class OrderOfInits {
    constructor() {
        println("constructor")
    }
    init {
        println("A")
    }
    init {
        println("B")
    }
    init {
        println("C")
    }
}

val a = OrderOfInits()
```

Would print:

```
A
B
C
constructor
```

Property delegates initialization is also part of primary constructor. Their initialization order in constructor reflects the order they were declared in. In other words the `init { fill(...) }` initializer block invokes `clientUrl` setter which in turn tries to call `Delegates.notNull()` instance method. However the instance field holding the `Delegates.notNull()` was not yet set hence NPE.

To fix the problem you just need to reorder them like so:

```
object WalletConfig {
    var clientUrl: String by Delegates.notNull()
        private set

    init {
        fill(HashMap<String, String>())
    }
    ...
}
```